# Keep getting error despite having defined delimiter character

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, procedure, mysql-command-line-client

I'm creating this procedure which should return a VARCHAR value as output. But I keep getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
> SELECT mgrType FROM Manager INTO mgType WHERE empNo=@eID;
> END

I have chosen // as new DELIMITER character so it is  not an issue with delimiter. Here's my code.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE returnEmpTy( IN un VARCHAR(40), IN pw VARCHAR(60), OUT mgType VARCHAR(30) )
BEGIN 
    DECLARE eID INT;
    SELECT empNo INTO eID FROM Employee WHERE username=un AND pssWrd=pw;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT @eID FROM Manager)
        BEGIN
            SELECT mgrType FROM Manager INTO mgType WHERE empNo=@eID;
        END
            
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

edit: resolved!

Comment: What resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code, but none of them have anything to do with the delimiter.

One problem is that `SELECT ... INTO` allows the `INTO` right before `FROM`, or at the end of the query, but not where you used it before `WHERE`. Review the examples in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Another is that you use `@eID` for the variable `eID`. These are not the same variable in MySQL.

Another is that you use `IF` without `THEN` or `END IF` and you have no `;` terminator anyway. You should refer the syntax and examples for MySQL's [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Another is that `IF/THEN/END IF` doesn't need a `BEGIN` block (unless you need to use `DECLARE` inside the block).

Your method of checking if the row exists in Manager is not going to do what you think. The EXISTS will return true if there are any rows in that table.

You don't need to check if there are rows in the table anyway. Just do the `SELECT ... INTO`. It'll assign NULL to `mgType` if there are no matching rows.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE returnEmpTy( IN un VARCHAR(40), IN pw VARCHAR(60), OUT mgType VARCHAR(30) )
BEGIN 
    DECLARE eID INT;
    SELECT empNo INTO eID FROM Employee WHERE username=un AND pssWrd=pw;

    SET mgType = NULL;
    SELECT mgrType FROM Manager WHERE empNo=eID INTO mgType;
            
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

You could simplify this further by using `JOIN` instead of a local variable:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE returnEmpTy( IN un VARCHAR(40), IN pw VARCHAR(60), OUT mgType VARCHAR(30) )
BEGIN 
    SELECT mgrType FROM Manager 
    JOIN Employee USING (empNo)
    WHERE username = un AND pssWrd = pw
    INTO mgType;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```